Topology on a module over a topological ring
The questions
Let $R$ be a topological ring, and let $M$ (with no topology) be an $R$-module. Does $M$ somehow "inherit" a topology from the action of $R$?
Here's a proposal for such a topology: let's define the module topology on $M$ to be the finest topology such that all $R$-linear maps $R^n\to M$ are continuous (here $n$ is a natural and $R^n$ has the product topology). This choice of topology is useful in some work I'm doing.
Q1) Has this topology has been written down before? Does it already have a name? More generally is there prior work on giving modules over a topological ring a topology (beyond my own work which I describe below in the background section)? Is my choice the "natural" choice or is there a better one? (I discuss three other choices below, and the problems with them).
Q2) I have proved several theorems about this topology above (in Lean). For example all $R$-linear maps between $R$-modules are automatically continuous if the modules are endowed with this topology. Restricting to finitely-generated modules I can prove much more: for example all $R$-bilinear maps $M\times N\to P$ are continuous if $M$ and $N$ are f.g., the action $R\times M\to M$ is continuous if $M$ is f.g. and so on. Are such claims true in general or is it naive to expect such a thing? As a concrete example of such a question: if $R$ is commutative and $A$ is an $R$-algebra with the module topology, is $A$ automatically a topological ring? I can only prove this under the assumption that $A$ is module-finite. If not, is there some modification of the definition which makes this true? I don't need the result in general (my applications are to finite-dimensional central simple algebras) but it is perhaps a more mathoverflowy question than Q1. I suspect that this sort of thing is hopeless though, e.g. infinite-dimensional vector spaces over a topological field often have several natural topologies.
The background
I become interested in this question when I was visiting the Hausdorff Institute in Bonn as part of the trimester on Prospects of formal mathematics, and decisive early work on the problem was done by Bonn undergraduates Hannah Scholz and Ludwig Monnerjahn who I met during my stay there. Hannah, Ludwig and I have almost finished a formalisation of a proof that if $R$ is commutative and if $A$ is a finite $R$-algebra, then the $R$-module topology on $A$ makes $A$ into a topological ring (i.e., multiplication is automatically continuous). We have also proved that the module topology on a finite free $R$-module is just the product topology.
The reason I was interested in these questions was because I'm formalising the proof of an $R=T$ theorem in Lean and to do this I need to define some adelic spaces of automorphic forms over quaternion algebras. So let $K$ be a number field and let $D/K$ be a quaternion algebra. An automorphic form for the algebraic group $D^\times/K$ is a continuous function on the topological group $(D\otimes_K\mathbb{A}_K)^\times$ such that...but immediately Lean objects that we need to prove it's a topological group, which boils down to proving that $D\otimes_K\mathbb{A}_K$ is a topological ring. Here $\mathbb{A}_K$ is the adeles
of $K$, a gigantic non-Noetherian topological ring which Lean's maths library already knows about.
So why is this tensor product ring a topological ring? In fact what even is the topology on this ring? Well $D$ is finite and free over $K$, so if we just pick a random basis for $D$ then $D$ becomes $K^4$ so $D\otimes_K\mathbb{A}_K$ becomes $(\mathbb{A}_K)^4$ which we can endow with the product topology. This reduces us to the problem of showing that multiplication is continuous for this topology, which is true because the function sending a pair of 2 by 2 matrices $(M,N)$ to their product $MN$ is continuous when considered as a function $\mathbb{A}_K^8\to \mathbb{A}_K^4$ because all its components are built using only addition and multiplication on $\mathbb{A}_K$, both of which are continuous.
There are two problems with that argument. Firstly, it's not clear that the topology is independent of the choice of basis (and this will come back to bite you later when you start developing the theory) (of course in old-fashioned pdf land you can just say "it is left as an exercise for the reader" or even "it is clear that the topology is independent..." on the basis that the proof of this just turns into another argument involving matrices of the form above).
The second problem is that, when you are formalising mathematics, this "choose a basis" attitude is something you want to avoid if possible, because the moment you choose a basis you leave the conceptual world of linear maps and are plunged into the clunky world of matrices, and arguments like the above become hard work to formalise. Formalisation pushes you towards thinking more conceptually and this benefits both you and your readers.
What I really wanted was some general purpose method for putting a topology on $D\otimes_K\mathbb{A}_K$ which didn't involve picking a basis and such that Lean would automatically discover the proof that it was a topological ring with respect to this choice. I remembered from reading Bosch-Guentzer-Remmert's book on nonarchimedean functional analysis that if $R$ was a certain kind of commutative complete normed ring then the objects in the category of finite $R$-modules inherited some nice norms and all morphisms magically became continuous. So I began to wonder in what generality this was true.
So let $R$ be a topological ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Here are four topologies that one could put on $M$, written down in the order which I tried them:

Coarsest topology making all $R$-linear maps $M\to R$ continuous.
Finest topology making all $R$-linear maps $R\to M$ continuous.
Finest topology making the $R$-action $R\times M \to M$ continuous (there is a short and elegant proof that there is a finest such topology)
Finest topology making all $R$-linear maps $R^n\to M$ continuous.

Scholz and Monnerjahn proved that choice (1) had the property that $R$-algebras which were finite and free as $R$-modules were automatically topological rings with this topology. But it's bad for quotients of $R$. (2) and (3) look like beautiful definitions but I was surprised to discover that neither of them work well for products: for example the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-module given by (2) and (3) is not the product topology, which is a disaster (for example for topology (2) a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open iff its intersection with all lines through the origin is open in the line when identified with $\mathbb{R}$). (4) was concocted by Adam Topaz in the discussion of the problem on the Lean Zulip and is the one I have gone with.

If you are in the finitely generated world, the definition seems eminently sensible (my instinct would have been the give M a quotient topology from a presentation, even if M is not finitely-generated; but then proving two presentations give the same topology might be chore, even if true)

@DavidRoberts To define a quotient topology from an arbitrary presentation you must give a topology on an infinite direct sum. Is it obvious how to do this?

@WillSawin like I said: "my first instinct". I didn't think it through, but the second instinct gives something probably equivalent to what Kevin wrote: put the colimit topology on the direct sum, over the finite free modules with the product topology, which then continuity amounts to continuity for maps from finite free modules etc etc etc.

"Finest topology making the map $R^n \times M^n \to M$ given by $((a_1,\dots,a_n), (b_1,\dots, b_n)) \to \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$ continuous" might be a natural way to produce a topology with the good properties of 4 but also ensuring the map $R \times M \to M$ is continuous. I don't see why this should suffice for bilinear maps to be continuous though.

The map $R\times M \to M$ is continuous if $R$ satisfies a mild hypothesis, that every element admits a bounded neighborhood. But it doesn't seem like that hypothesis is enough to make bilinear maps continuous.

@DavidRoberts indeed for my definition I've proved that if $M\to N$ is surjective then it's "coinducing" (do people say that? I mean the pushforward of the topology on $M$ equals the topology on $N$) for f.g. modules. Will's comment about not knowing how to put a topology on arbitrary direct sums was precisely what stopped me from going further down this line, because I only needed a definition which would give me e.g. that f.d. central simple algebras over top fields are automatically top. rings with the module topology, and that the module top equals the product top for finite products.

I don't want to use maps from arbitrary products of R's with the product topology, because there's no reason to expect and R-linear map from that to R to be continuous, even if R is the reals you can just use AC to make discontinuous ones. But I don't want to embed the sum into the product and use the subspace topology eiher, because I recently realised (you can probably guess why) that the adeles are typically defined as a subring of an infinite product of top fields, but don't have the subspace topology coming from this product.

The first two links 404 for me.

@WillSawin I have fixed the links

@KevinBuzzard If you're not already aware of this reference, it may be worth looking up Helemskii's The Homology of Banach and Topological Algebras (Springer, 1989) and more widely the literature generated by Helemskii's school over the years. I'm not sure if it addresses your question directly, but it certainly goes through a whole zoo of relationships between algebras/rings, modules and their topologies.

I think the right definition to use in general is "The finest topology making multiplication $R \times M \to M$ and addition $M \times M \to M$ continuous". This has the obvious advantage of making $M$ a topological $R$-module and being universal among all such topologies. This is a simpler form of my  suggestion in a comment. I think the same proof you give in Lean for definition 3 shows that this finest topology exists.
This is similar to your definition 3. The defect in 3 is that it doesn't include the continuity of $M \times M\to M$. This is always coarser than the definition 4, since any map $R^n \to M$ can be written as a composition of maps $R \to M$ and addition maps $M \times M \to M$, and maps $R\to M$ can be written as compositions of multiplication $R\times M \to M$ and inclusions $\{x\} \to M$.
This topology still has the property that an $R$-module homomorphism $M \to N$ is necessarily continuous. Indeed the pullback of the topology on $N$ is itself a topology on $M$ such that $R\times M \to M$ and $M \times M \to M$ are continuous.
It has the property that the topology on $M \times N$ is the product of the topology on $M$ and the topology on $N$. Indeed the product topology makes the product a topological module, so this topology is finer than the product topology. To check this topology is coarser than the product topology, use that $M \to M \times N$ and $N \to M \times N$ are $R$-module homomorphisms, hence continuous, and then compose with addition $(M \times N) \times (M\times N) \to (M\times N)$.
This does not have your desired property about maps $M \times N \to P$, but I will show below that no topology which satisfies other reasonable desiderata has that property.

The  topology 4 does not have the property that all bilinear maps $M \times N \to P$ are continuous for this topology without finiteness assumptions on $M$ or $N$. Indeed, the argument shows that no topology such that all $R$-linear maps $R^n \to M$ are continuous, and with the topology on $R$ the usual one, has the bilinear map property, so any topology with the bilinear map property must lack some other desirable property.
Let $R$ be $\mathbb Q_p$ with the usual topology. Let $M = \bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb N} \mathbb Q_p$, let $N =\prod_{i\in \mathbb N} \mathbb Q_p$, let $P= \mathbb Q_p$, and let $M \otimes N \to \mathbb Q_p$ send $((a_1,a_2,\dots) ,(b_1,b_2,\dots) ) $ (with all but finitely many of $a_1,a_2,\dots$ zero) to $\sum_{i\in \mathbb N} a_i b_i$.
I will show that the inverse image of $\mathbb Z_p$ in $P$ does not contain an open neighborhood of $(0,0) \in M\times N$.
The topology on $M$ has the property that a set is open (if and) only if its restriction to $R^n$ for each $n$ is open for the usual product topology. It follows by induction on $n$ that each open subset of zero includes $\{ (a_1,a_2,\dots) \in \bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb N}^{\mathbb Q_p} \mid a_i \in p^{c_i} \mathbb Z_p \textrm{ for all } i\}$ for some sequence of integers $c_i$. (The inductive step is that any open subset of $R^n$ containing $\{a_1,\dots,a_n \in R \mid a_i \in p^{c_i} \mathbb Z_p \textrm{ for } i<n, a_n=0\}$ contains $\{a_1,\dots,a_n \in R \mid a_i \in p^{c_i} \mathbb Z_p \textrm{ for } i\leq n\}$ for some $c_n$, which follows from the compactness of $\{a_1,\dots,a_n \in R \mid a_i \in p^{c_i} \mathbb Z_p \textrm{ for } i<n, a_n=0\}$ .)
So for an element $U \times V$ of the standard basis for the product topology of $M \times N$, with $0\in U$, to lie in the inverse image of $\mathbb Z_p$, $V$ would have to be contained in $\{ (b_1,b_2,\dots) \in \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Q_p \mid b_i \in p^{ -c_i } \mathbb Z_p \textrm{ for all } i \}$.
But if any such set $V$ with $0\in V$ is open, then there exists a map $\mathbb Q_p \to N$ that is not continuous, e.g. the unique map sending $1$ to the sequence $(b_1,b_2,\dots)$ with $b_i = p^{-c_i-i}$, for which the inverse image of $V$ is the singleton $\{0\}$ and hence is not open.
So no element $U \times V$ of the standard basis for the product topology of $M \times N$ with $(0,0)\in U \times V$ lies in the inverse image of $\mathbb Z_p$, which since $(0,0)$ lies in the inverse image of $\mathbb Z_p$ implies the inverse imge of $\mathbb Z_p$ is not open, contradicting continuity of $M \times N \to P$.
It should be possible to make this bilinear counterexample (or any bilinear counterexample) into a counterexample to an algebra version by considering the ring $R \times M \times N \times P$ with a multiplication in which $M^2 = N^2 = P^2 = MP = NP = 0 $ and the other multiplications are the obvious ones.

I look at answers like this now and my first two thoughts are (a) wooah thanks Will I really want to read this and then (b) ...but actually I wish it was just written in Lean not LaTeX, it would be much easier to understand because I can just click around the statements and proofs. If someone wants to PR the construction to the Lean FLT repo in the HIM-experiments folder with Will's code as comments then I'd definitely be interested. Import FLT.ForMathlib.ModuleTopology, get GH copilot or whatever to translate the post into Lean 4 and then fix up the crap you get :-)

@KevinBuzzard If you want to get someone to do that probably posting a comment to this MO answer is not the best way. I would do it if I knew how, probably. I have edited to include what I suspect is the right definition, which has all the good properties of definition 4 and also the good properties of definition 3.

Re the suggested topology: this is now the 5th suggestion I've had and to be honest I do like the look of it.

@KevinBuzzard Cool! An additional feature I noticed is that it is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from topological $R$-modules to $R$-modules. (The right adjoint endows a module with the trivial topology.)

Update: The product claim checks out: https://github.com/ImperialCollegeLondon/FLT/blob/main/FLT/HIMExperiments/Sawin_topology.lean . Also the topology on R is R's usual topology. What I can't prove is that quotients of R get the quotient topology. This was true for topology 4 (the R^n one). Maybe this isn't true for your topology? I don't need it in my application though.

@KevinBuzzard I convinced myself that it does, in fac that a quotient $M$ of a module $N$ gets the quotient topology. Any topology that makes $N$ a topological module pulls back to a topology that makes $M$ a topological model and hence is coarser than the topology on $M$, so it suffices to prove the topology on $M$ is finer than the quotient topology, in other words that the quotient topology makes $M$ a topological module.

The key claim is that in the quotient topology the image of any open set is open, since we can take a union of the open set with its translates to make it invariant under translating by $\operatorname{ker} (N \to M)$. Now to show $M \times M \to M$ is continuous with the quotient topology, take an open set $U$ on $M$, two points $x,y$ in $M$ such that $x+y$ is in the open set $U$. Lift $x$ and $y$, then the sum of the lifts lies in the inverse image of $U$, hence the lifts have neighborhoods whose sum lies in the inverse image of $U$, and the images of those neighborhoods in $M$ do the trick.

This is pretty much the technique I used to prove that topology 4 had this property. I ran into a problem that (to my great surprise) the pushforward of a product topology was not the product of the pushforward topologies in general. However this is true for surjective group homomorphisms and the key point in the argument is the observation you point out above -- quotients are open maps when they're group homomorphisms: https://github.com/ImperialCollegeLondon/FLT/blob/20abe47cf38ef415eaaffa87c159e5c19950c313/FLT/ForMathlib/MiscLemmas.lean#L18 .

When $R$ is a complete metric field, say $\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb Q_p$ ... then the topology on a finite-dimensional $R$-vector space $M$ is unique.
But for a non-complete field $R$, this is no longer true.
Example, $R = \mathbb Q$ with the usual absolute value; and $M = \{(a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$.  Two different topolgies are obtained with norms
(1) $\|(a,a)\| = |a| + |b|$ or
(2) $\|(a,b)\| = |a+b\sqrt{2}|$

Yes there is a big zoo of topologies that one can put on $R^2$ in general. I just needed something which worked for my application, which in particular needed to work for all modules, needed to be the ring's topology for $R$, and the product topology for something isomorphic to $R^n$.
